# white foam on mulberry, ants love it

Tags: trees, diseases, mulberry

What is this white foamy thing I see sometimes on leaves and sometimes on small branches on my mulberry tree. (Don't forget to read updates below pictures.)

[image]

[image]

**Update:**
I gather 3 of these foams, and tried to explore them. There was something black (or more like dark red) in the middle of each. Doesn't feel like some insect, because it wasn't moving, but felt more like egg of something.So, I broke it and it was bloody.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't *really* tell from these pictures, but frequently there's an aphid under the foam, making it from the sap of your plant.

Comment: I have added update @Ecnerwal